# Merge two arrays into one by key

Tags: swift

I have two Arrays. I want to use them, to create the new one. Then, the new list will be use in the List View. So how it looks like? I have two models that are the basis for lists:

Photo:

```
class Photo: Object, Identifiable, Decodable {
@objc dynamic var albumId: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var title: String = ""
@objc dynamic var url: String = ""
@objc dynamic var thumbnailUrl: String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
}
```

Album:

```
class Album: Object, Decodable {
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var userId: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var title: String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

}
```

The child of both is ListItem. So the vars of the ItemLists are using vars from the Photo and Album classes. I hope I explained it well. If not, please ask.

```
class ListItem {
var id: Int = 0                Album id
var title: String = ""         Photo title
var albumTitle: String = ""    Album title
var thumbnailUrl: String = ""  Photo thumbnailUrl

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to merge the 2 arrays together, then call `map` to create `ListItem`s from each element.

```
let list = zip(photos, albums).map { photo, album in ListItem(id: album.id, title: photo.title, albumTitle: album.title, thumbnailUrl: photo.thumbnailUrl)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question directly you have a one to many relationship between Album and Photo so for each Photo we should look up the correct Album and create a new ListItem

This can be done using this code

```
let list: [ListItem] = photoArray.compactMap { photo in
    guard let album = albumArray.first(where: { $0.id == photo.id }) else {
        return nil
    }

    return ListItem(id: album.id, title: photo.title, albumTitle: album.title, thumbnailUrl: photo.url)
}
```